# Dll making with C++

Tags: visual-c++, plugins, dll

I'm been trying to start doing a plug-in for a program called "Euroscope" for quite some time and i still can't do anything. I even read a C++ book and nothing, it's too difficult to start. 
The question i'm going to ask is a little bit specific and it's going to be difficult to explain but i'm tired of trying to solve this by my own so here it comes.

I have a class that i imported with a bunch of function prototypes in the header called "EuroscopePlugIn".

My principal .cpp is this:

```
void CPythonPlugInScreen::meu()
{
//loop over the planes
EuroScopePlugIn::CAircraft ac;
EuroScopePlugIn::CAircraftFlightPlan acfp;
CString str;
CPythonPlugIn object;

for(ac=GetPlugIn()->AircraftSelectFirst();
ac.IsValid();
ac=GetPlugIn()->AircraftSelectNext(ac))
{
EuroScopePlugIn::CAircraftPositionData acpos=ac.GetPosition();
const char *c=ac.GetCallsign();
object.printtofile_simple_char(*c);
object.printtofile_simple_int(ac.GetState());


};
object.printtofile_simple_int(ac.GetVerticalSpeed());
object.printtofile_simple_int(acfp.GetFinalAltitude());

cout<<acfp.GetAlternate();
}
```

the "printtofile_simple_int" and "printtofile_simple_char" are defined is the class CPythonPlugIn like this:

```
void printtofile_simple_int(int n){
    ofstream textfile;
    textfile.open("FP_simple_int.txt");
    textfile<<(n);
    textfile.close();
```

So i open the program, load the .dll i created with Build->Solution and it does nothing, the .txt files aren't even created and even the cout produces nothing.
I will give you some of the prototype infos on the header file "EuroScopePlugIn.h" in case you need them to understand my micro program. If you need other,ask me and i'll put it here

```
//---GetPlugIn-----------------------------------------------------

    inline  CPlugIn * GetPlugIn ( void )
        {
        return m_pPlugIn ;
        } ;
```

&

```
CAircraft   AircraftSelectFirst ( void ) const ;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Return :
    //      An aircraft object instance.
    //
    //  Remark:
    //      This instance is only valid inside the block you are querying.
    //      Do not save it to a static place or into a member variables.
    //      Subsequent use of an invalid extracted route reference may
    //      cause ES to crash.
    //
    //  Description :
    //      It selects the first AC in the list. 
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

&

```
int     GetFinalAltitude ( void ) const ;
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Return :
    //      The final requested altitude.
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please guys i need help to start with the plug-in making, from that point on with a methodology of trial and error i'll be on my way. I'm just finding it extremely hard to start...

Thank you very much for the help

Comment: If your program compiles, you need to look at your "Euroscope" software. I would assume the plugin is not exactly as they expect it to be (missing method, etc.) so they don't start it. Do they offer some debugging capabilities or log files when plugins are not loaded successfully?

Comment: i don't know. I'm pretty sure the plug-in is being loaded as i see it in the list of the plug-ins in the program. The question is that maybe he is doing nothing and the thing is:unfortunately i don't know how to change that -_-

Comment: Can you debug the DLL? Visual Studio will let you start the exe program, then when you load the DLL you will hit breakpoints in the DLL if it is loaded.

Comment: If Euroscope is a GUI application there is no cout. You can, however, build strings and output them with the OutputDebugString API.

Comment: Yes i can Debug it, and i do it through "Euroscope.exe". I don't understand the 2nd part of the answer,can you explain please?

Comment: Yeah i suspected that. The cout was just a shallow attempt because the "printofile" weren't working. I will look into OutputDebugString API

Comment: The debugger will halt your code at desired points: "breakpoints". To make a breakpoint click in the left margin of the line of code you would like to stop at. When it stops you can examine variables by hovering the mouse over the variable.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the answer. Well it seems that i've encountered an error while debugging, and maybe my whole problem is because of it. "Debugging information for 'Euroscope.exe' cannot be found or does not match. Binary was not built with debug information. Do you want to continue debugging?" I did everything i found on the internet and i still have this error. Any idea?
Thank you